Bertrands Postulate - Version $2n-2$

For $n>3$ there is always a prime $p$ s.t.
$$
n<p<2n-2.
$$


Question: Is there a simple modification of Erdős' proof for Bertrands postulate (version $n<p<2n$) to show this slightly stronger version?

In the original proof, we assume that there are no prime numbers $p$ with $n<p\leq 2n$. According to a Lemma, there are also no prime divisors of $N=\binom{2n}{n}$ in the interval $(\frac{2}{3}n, n]$. It follows that all prime factors of $N$ must lie in the interval $[2, \frac{2}{3}n]$. We continue an estimation that gives a contradiction.
From the proof I understand that the modification has to be somewhere where we show that if $p^k\mid N$ then $p^k\leq 2n$. This has to be reduced to $2n-1$ to show the above claim. Is this possible?

Ramanujan derived that for any positive integer $k$, there is a natural number $N$ such that for all $n > N$, there are at least $k$ primes between $n$ and $2n$. If we set $k=2$ and assume that $2n-1$ is prime, then there has to be a prime below $2n-2$ proving the stronger version. However I am interested in a modification of the proof for $n<p<2n$.


Just a small remark. $p=2n-2=2(n-1)$ is not prime for $n>3$. It is not difficult to modify the usual prove to see that one can chose $p$ with $p<2n-1$.

I think that's the usual formulation, see Wikipedia for example.  In any case, even stronger results are known.

@lulu Yeah, compared to really strong results, this is still weak. However, I cannot find this in any book, only the version with $2n$. And I dont know how to obtain this slightly stronger version.

Probably there are better references, but this question contains links to papers proving Bertrand with specified congruence properties, and that suffices.

If it ehelps: In the paper referenced on Wikipedia, Bertrand speaks of "$p$ une nombre premier entre $n-2$ and $\frac n2$"

The same question was asked here already. The comments confirm that you can adapt the standard proof by Erdös.
